# Cannot get string value to run function within a function

Tags: swift, struct, google-places-autocomplete

I am trying to write an autocomplete function for Google Places, I have written the function and it works.  The only challenge I am running into, is I need to get the zip code of each "place" which requires me to run an additional function.  That function also works on its own.  What I need to do is get the autocomplete prediction, which could be 123 Any Street, and then take that places "place ID" and get its zip code, and then put it in a struct which is in an array (all the structs are in the array) so that it returns the info all at once.

What I can't figure out is how to get the "place ID" out of the first set of results to run the function.  Using compactMap, flatMap and map all are not working.  using [0] works, but only is getting the first zipcode in the array, which doesn't help.  If someone could point me into the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

```
    public func findPlaces(
    query: String,  <- user typing in address
    completion: @escaping (Result<[Place], Error>) -> Void
) {
    let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
    filter.types = ["geocode"]
    filter.countries = ["US"]
    client.findAutocompletePredictions(
        fromQuery: query,
        filter: filter,
        sessionToken: nil
    ) { results, error in
        guard let results = results, error == nil else {
            completion(.failure(PlacesError.failedToFind))
            return
        }
        
        let myPlaceID = results[0].placeID  <- Place ID of only the first place in array, I need all of them
        
        self.client.fetchPlace(fromPlaceID: myPlaceID,
                               placeFields: [.coordinate, .addressComponents],
                          sessionToken: nil
        ) { googlePlace, error in
            guard let googlePlace = googlePlace, error == nil else {
                completion(.failure(PlacesError.failedToGetCoordinates))
                return
            }
            
            var zipCodeString = ""
            if let addressComponent = googlePlace.addressComponents?.first(where: {$0.types.contains("postal_code")})?.name {
               zipCodeString = addressComponent
            }
            print("Zipcode is \(zipCodeString)")

            let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                latitude: googlePlace.coordinate.latitude,
                longitude: googlePlace.coordinate.longitude
            )
            let places: [Place] = results.compactMap({
                Place(
                    name: $0.attributedPrimaryText.string,
                    identifier: $0.placeID,
                    detail: Utils.shared.removeCountryFromPlace(string: $0.attributedFullText.string),
                    coords: PlaceCoords(withCoords: coordinate),
                    zipcode: zipCodeString
                )
            })
            completion(.success(places))
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the "Place" struct:

```
struct Place: Codable {
  let name: String
  let identifier: String
  let detail: String
  let coords: PlaceCoords
  let zipcode: String
}

struct PlaceCoords: Codable {
  let latData: Double?
  let lonData: Double?

  init(withCoords coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    self.latData = coord.latitude
    self.lonData = coord.longitude
  }

  func getCoords() -> CLLocationCoordinate2D? {
    guard let latData = self.latData, let lonData = self.lonData else { return nil }
    let placeCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latData, longitude: lonData)
    return placeCoord
  }
}
```

Comment: Why isn’t map etc working, it should be the right tool for the job? Could you add your attempt at using map and explain why it gives the wrong result?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I am not using the map at all, there is no need for this.  All the user is doing is "typing" in a text field, an address.  555 Main Street, Boston they type as an example, and it shows a table with the autocomplete predictions.

Comment: I am of course talking about the function `map` that you mentioned in your question (together with flatMap and compactMap)

Comment: The problem is that `fetchPlace` is a second asynchronous call. You need a loop to iterate the places and `DispatchGroup` to get notified when all tasks have completed. But maybe the API supports `async/await` then take advantage of that.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson sorry for the misunderstanding.  It was able to identify the item, but it would not extract it as a string value, even with a VAR or LET statement

Comment: @vadian I had this also a separate function with a completion handler, but I wasn't sure how I could iterate all of the place id's that came up in the function I have listed above.  when you use [0] it works as intended, but i don't want the first item every since there are many responses

Comment: `let placeIdentifiers = results.map(\.placeID)` will give you an array of Place ID values.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes thats correct, but I need each place ID to hit that other function, and take its response and combine it into the Place struct, which is part of a place array.  So, how do I get the right place ID associated with the correct row in the table so to speak.

Comment: As I said: *You need a loop to iterate the places and `DispatchGroup` to get notified when all tasks have completed.*

Comment: @vadian ok, I will work on that